# Upper bound for ratio of positive terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics, inequality

Suppose $x,y \ge 0$ and $a > 1.$ Do there exist constants $c_1, c_2 \in [0,\infty)$ which do not depend on $x$ or $y$ such that $$\frac{a + \frac{x}{2y}}{a-\frac{1}{2}} \le c_1x + c_2y$$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takie $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ , $y_n =\frac{1}{n^2}$ and observe that's such constans cannot exist.